# Return a list of even numbers in SML

Tags: sml

I have been learning SML, which has proven to be quite the undertaking. I am trying to create a function that takes in a list of integers then returns only the even numbers within that list.

Here is what I have so far:

```
fun isEven [] = [] |
    val evenList            
    if x mod 2 = 1 then //append to evenList
```

I am very stuck on what I'm supposed to be doing next. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: `List.filter (fn i => i mod 2 = 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example (and for most list-processing problems), it is often easiest to begin by considering two possibilities: either the list is empty, or it is not. When the list is empty, the problem is probably trivial to solve. When the list is not empty, you can deconstruct the list into two pieces: the first element (the "head"), and the rest of the elements (the "tail").

In code, we can write many different versions of a function depending what the input looks like. Below I'm pattern matching on the input and writing two different function bodies, depending on whether the input is empty or not. When it is not empty, the head of the list is bound to a variable `x` and the tail is bound to a variable `xs`:

```
fun f []        = (* ... empty case ... *)
  | f (x :: xs) = (* ... non-empty case ... *)
```

Under this "idiomatic" approach, you can then ask: how do I solve the problem *recursively* when the list is non-empty? That is, is it possible to apply the same function to the tail of the list, and use that to construct the final answer?

```
fun f []        = (* ... TODO: trivial when list is empty ... *)
  | f (x :: xs) =
      let
        val foo = f xs
      in
        (* ... TODO: how to use `foo`? ... *)
      end
```

At this point, I'll leave the rest to you. Try to fill in the gaps: What does `foo` represent in your problem? What do you need to do with the head element, `x`?

Answer (score 0):

A function called `isEven` sounds like a predicate, rather than a filter.

```
fun isEven n =
    n mod 2 = 0
```

You could call it `evens`:

```
fun evens [] = ... (* base case *)
  | evens (n::ns) = ... (* recursive case *)
```

Now you can call `isEven` to determine if the first `n` of `n::ns` (there is at least one, since otherwise the function would have matched the base case rather than the recursive case) is even:

```
if isEven n then ... else ...
```

Note that *if-then-else* in SML *has* to have an *else* part.

In either case, you want to keep finding evens on `ns`, but you only want to include `n` in the result depending on the value of `isEven n`. You include something in the result by creating a new list in which `n` is also a member. For example, a function that increments each element in a list by 1:

```
fun incr [] = []
  | incr (n::ns) = n+1 :: incr ns
```

Except, in the case of `evens`, you don't want to modify `n`, and the `n :: ...` part is conditional.